# Setting up symfony2 translation

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, translation

I want to create translation for my app in sympfony 2. I create selector like this :

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'sr'})) }}">Serbian</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">English</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Now in my url i get ...`?_locale=en`, also i have folder structure like :

```
MyAppBudnle/
-Resources
--translations
---messages.sr.yml - File with translations.
```

And also in mu `App/config/config.yml` i have this line :

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: en }
```

...

Can you tell me now, what more i need to create so, that translation start working. my app is on english, and when i change it to SR it should be on Serbian..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle locale change in event like onKernelRequest and pass locale to session (if needed - you can prepare your routes to handle _locale part, router should handle it automatically) and pass it to Request. Every text written in app should be translated of course with {{ "lorem ispum"|trans }}.
Good luck!